# Multi-Selection dynamic menus

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I'm looking to create `Dynamic` menus with multiple options that would allow multiple selections.

For example, mousing over an object (let's say a black circle of radius 1), a menu would popup at `MousePosition[]` with two options of "red" and "5". Selecting "red" would create a new circle, red with radius of 1, and selecting both would give a red circle of radius = 5.

How would I create temporary/dynamic menus similar to the standard right-click (disappears after clicking away), except with multi-selection?

**Edit:** I got carried away with my end-goal example. All I am wondering is if `Panel` is the correct function to use here with multiple `Checkbox`es (the documentation examples did not have what I expected).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Jun/msg00306.html), this may get you started. If I have time, I will port that answer here as an answer.

Comment: THanks Leonid, I'll look through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{color = Gray, radius = 1, ww = {}},
Mouseover[
   Graphics[{Dynamic@color, Disk[{0, 0}, Dynamic@radius], Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 3]}],
   Dynamic[Panel[CheckboxBar[
      Dynamic[ww, {(ww = #; radius = If[MemberQ[ww, 1], 2, 1]; 
              color = If[MemberQ[ww, 2], Red, Gray]) &}],
      {1 -> "radius = 2", Delimiter, 2 -> "color = Red"},
   Appearance -> "Vertical", Appearance -> Small]]],
   ImageSize -> All]]
```

Screenshots:

view when mouse is over the panel:

[image]

views when mouse is off the panel:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ahhh beautiful ~~Thank you. Could you explain why there are two Panels in your code? I believe the second Panel creates the panel with the checkboxbar, but what does the first line (Panel@DynamicModule) do? edit: oh wait, one of them makes the circle...?

Comment: @Twoday, the outer panel  is not essential. I used it to get the screenshots -- to crop the prt-scr image to appropriate size.